# Running a Linux Console Command in C#

Tags: c#, mono

I am using the following code to run a Linux console command via Mono in a C# application:

```
ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("/bin/bash", "-c ls");
procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
proc.StartInfo = procStartInfo;
proc.Start();

String result = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```

This works as expected. But, if i give the command as `"-c ls -l"` or `"-c ls /path"` I still get the output with the `-l` and `path` ignored.

What syntax should I use in using multiple switches for a command?

Comment: You could try using `ProcessStartInfo.Arguments` to see if the alternative method works?  Also do you need the /bin/bash? can you not just run 'ls' direct?

Comment: @cjb110 no it doesn't work. Yes you do have to set /bin/bash as the filename or it cannot find the bash executable on its own.

Comment: Maybe try RedirectStandardInput and send the commands.  I don't know the exact code but I do know you can do this to send input to the process.  Here is a sample:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardinput(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Is there a solution to this problem? I am having the same one.

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to **quote** the command.

Did you try the following on the bash prompt ?

```
bash -c ls -l
```

I strongly suggest to read the [man bash](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Invoking-Bash).
And also the getopt manual as it's what bash use to parse its parameters.

It has exactly the same behavior as `bash -c ls` 
Why? Because you have to tell bash that `ls -l` is the full argument of `-c`, otherwise `-l` is treated like an argument of bash.
Either `bash -c 'ls -l'` or `bash -c "ls -l"` will do what you expect.
You have to add quotes like this:

```
ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("/bin/bash", "-c 'ls -l'");
```

Comment: bash -c 'ls -l' is almost the same as bash -c "ls -l" but doesn't require escaping in C# string