# "docker ps" accepts no arguments in C# and CMD

Tags: c#, docker, cmd, process

In the project, I want to get the output from progress with the command `docker ps -a --format '{{json .}}'`

But the process error with `"docker ps" accepts no arguments`

Here is the code in C#

```
 var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("docker")
        {
            UseShellExecute = false,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            RedirectStandardError = true,
            CreateNoWindow = true,
            Arguments = "ps -a --format '{{json .}}'",
            WorkingDirectory = workingDirectory
        };
        var process = Process.Start(startInfo);
```

The command in terminal is running ok. and I test in cmd like this `cmd /c "docker ps -a  --format '{{json .}}'"` it output the same error with C#

So How to solve it?

Thanks.

Comment: What happens when you test the command `docker ps "-a --format '{{json .}}'"` (with the quotes)? Or `docker ps -a --format {{json .}}'` without the quotes? I believe something in c# is parsing these differently than the shell.

Comment: There does appear to be a [Docker SDK](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/sdk/) library for C# and using that might be easier to work with than trying to run `docker` commands.  I get an "accept no arguments" error if I bypass the shell running that command; `docker ps -a --format \'{{json . }}\'`; and it seems like a shell isn't being invoked to handle the single quotes in that command.

Comment: @BMitch both not working, the same error.

Comment: @DavidMaze Can not work, I find the alternative implement in the SDK, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To anyone who come with the same issue, I found my solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32667955)
Call `bash` instead of call the `docker` directly.
For example, calling `docker ps -a --format '{{json .}}'`

```
 var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("bash")
        {
            UseShellExecute = false,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            RedirectStandardError = true,
            CreateNoWindow = true,
            Arguments = "-c \"docker ps -a --format '{{json .}}'\"",
            WorkingDirectory = workingDirectory
        };
        var process = Process.Start(startInfo);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with nodejs. The issue is that `cmd` doesn't like this bit: `'{{json .}}'`. Instead of `Arguments` you should use `ArgumentList` like that:

```cs
var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("docker")
{
    UseShellExecute = false,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        RedirectStandardError = true,
        CreateNoWindow = true,
        ArgumentList = {"ps", "-a", "--format", "{{json .}}"},
        WorkingDirectory = workingDirectory
};
var process = Process.Start(startInfo);
```